# TSQL SELECT DISTINCT with order by ASC NULLS last

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, distinct, sql-order-by

Having:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 * FROM mytable ORDER BY date ASC
```

How can I make the nulls in date go last?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some databases support a syntax for NULLs last in an `order by` and some do not.  So, I use:

```
select distinct top 100 *
from MyTable
order by  (case when date is null then 1 else 0 end), date asc
```

Or, if I don't want to type so much:

```
order by coalesce(date, '9999-12-12')  -- or something like that
```

You can also put the distinct in a subquery:

```
select top 100 *
from (select distinct *
      from mytable
     ) t
order by (case when date is null then 1 else 0 end), date asc
```

Assuming that `date` is in the column list, however, the first version should work.

Comment: Only the last piece of code (subquery) works for me. In real life the query is huge, full of joins, is there any other way to order by nulls last without changing the select part? Thanks again!

Comment: @MiguelMas . . . Can you ask another question, showing more of your query?  Something is going on that this simple example is missing.  Also, what version of SQL Server are you using?